# Reduce the over use of files in text processing

Tags: sed, awk

Currently, I have a file (`Results.txt`) which has 27k rows. The file content is as below.

```
45008657        |       A.      |               |       Long    |       0
49210987        |       A.      |               |       Steven  |       3262
49600694        |       A.      |               |       Steven    |       4772
467814  |       A.      |       Rafeal    |       Nadal|       4133
53111047        |       A.      |       Mike    |       Tyson  |       13484
```

I need to remove the extra white spaces, which am doing like below.

```
cat Results.txt | tr -d " \t\r" > Results1.txt
```

The file (`Results1.txt`) is neatly formatted with no extra white spaces.

```
45008657|A.||Long|0
49210987|A.||Steven|3262
49600694|A.||Steven|4772
467814|A.|Rafeal|Nadal|4133
53111047|A.|Mike|Tyson|13484
```

Now, I need to convert all the alphabets to lowercase and append columns 2 to 4.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|" } ; { print $1"|"tolower($2) tolower($3) tolower($4)"|"$5 }' Results1.txt > Results2.txt
```

My `Results2.txt` file will look like below.

```
45008657|a.long|0
49210987|a.steven|3262
49600694|a.steven|4772
467814|a.rafealnadal|4133
53111047|a.miketyson|13484
```

Is there any way I could accomplish all the above mentioned steps in my initial file (`Results.txt`) itself? I want to reduce over usage of files so that it would be easy for debugging in later stages.

**EDIT**: I simply do not want to remove the files once after creating a new file which doesn't seem an elegant solution to me.

Comment: In the `tr` command, you do not need to `cat` the file. You can do it as follows: `tr -d " \t\r" < Results.txt > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt  Results.txt`

Comment: For what you want to do, you can write vim macros. Then, things will get edited within vim and you won't need to save intermediate files.

Comment: Thanks. I will check vim macros. For now, I think I will stick to devnull's answer with your mv approach. :)

Comment: you could first lower case with `dd if=input.txt of=output.txt conv=lcase` then ... let the unicorn decide

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/\s//g;s/\(|[^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)|/\1\2/;s/.*/\L&/' Results.txt
```

Comment: This command is the one I am looking for. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this would skip the third field.  (That is, the resulting output would be different from the _expected_ output in the question.)

Comment: @devnull, indeed. I had misread the requirements. Should be OK now.

Comment: Couldn't you do this with any *`sed`* if you just *`y/A-Z/a-z/`?*

Comment: Apologies for the nitpick.  However, it seems that the question wasn't clear enough (given that the previous version of your answer was accepted)!

Comment: @mikeserv, no, you'd need `y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/` but then that would only work for ASCII letters, you'd also need `[[:space:]]` instead of `\s` and you couldn't use `-i`.

Comment: Thanks, Stephane. I came close to your example yesterday when I was trying it but I used one *`tr`* because I wasn't really sure how *`y`* worked. The ASCII requirement is definitely an eye-opener.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a temporary file, indeed.

```
awk -F'|' '{gsub("[ \t\r]", "", $0)}{print $1,tolower($2$3$4),$5}' OFS='|' inputfile
```

The first part of the expression does what you do using `tr`.  The second part conbines fields 2-4 and lowercases those and prints it with the other two fields.

For your input, it'd produce:

```
45008657|a.long|0
49210987|a.steven|3262
49600694|a.steven|4772
467814|a.rafealnadal|4133
53111047|a.miketyson|13484
```

---

GNU awk 4.1.0 and higher support in-place editing.  You can say:

```
awk -i inplace -F'|' '{gsub("[ \t\r]", "", $0)}{print $1,tolower($2$3$4),$5}' OFS='|' inputfile
```

Comment: Yeah, but the inputfile needs to be saved as different file after getting the output right? I need only the `inputfile` alone.

Comment: For now, I will stick to your answer with ketan's mv approach. Thanks :)

Comment: @Ramesh GNU awk 4.1.0 and higher support in-place editing.  Updating the answer.

Comment: unfortunately my server has awk 3.1.5 version only. But anyways thanks for the information :)

Comment: stephane's and terdon's commands were much closer to what I originally intended to achieve. :)

Answer (score 4):

With your original attempt, you can put all the commands in the same pipeline if you use the `sponge` utility:

```
cat Results.txt |
  tr -d " \t\r" |
  awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|" } ;
    { print $1"|"tolower($2) tolower($3) tolower($4)"|"$5 }' |
    sponge Results.txt
```

`sponge` will store its `stdin` in memory until it reaches the end of input, then write to file. This should be acceptable for a file of the size mentioned.

Note you can also use a shell redirection to input a file to `td` rather than `cat`, eg:

```
tr -d " \t\r" <Results.txt
```

Comment: thanks for letting me know about `sponge` command. I will check it out :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use a tool that allows in place editing. Perl for example:

```
perl -i -F'\|' -lane 's/[ \t]+//g for @F; print lc("$F[0]|$F[1]$F[2]$F[3]|$F[4]")' a
```

- The `-i` turns on in-plcae editing, the changes are applied directly to the original file (in other words, `perl` deals with creating and deleting the temp file).
- The `-a` turns on automatic splitting on the character given by `-F`, the fields are saved in the array `@F`.
- The `s/[ \t]+//g` removes all spaces and tabs and the `lc()` makes everything lowercase.

Comment: it is perfect. But however, I get the output as, `45008657|a.long0|` instead of `45008657|a.long|0`. The command that you had mentioned seems to have the `|` at correct place only. Is there any other reason for the misplaced `|`?

Comment: @Ramesh I can't reproduce. I tried this on the example you gave and it works as expected.

Comment: stephane's solution was something which I originally intended to achieve :) I am still puzzled on why the `|` gets misplaced after the last column using the `perl` solution.

Comment: @Ramesh that should only happen if you are missing a `|` in the input file. I can't think of any other reason and as I said, I can't reproduce it with your example. Stephane's is better though (as usual).